# Workflow with ember-data and ajax api call

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this code in routes/index.js:

```
model() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    maps: ajax({
      url: '*********************',
      type: 'get' 
    }).then(function(data) {
      console.log('maps: ', data);
      return data; 
    })
  });
}
```

which returns json data. Now I want to work with ember-data and a model, i have this code in models/map.js:

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.Model.extend({
  gmap_lat_center: DS.attr('string'), 
  gmap_long_center: DS.attr('string'), 
  hotspots: DS.attr('array'), 
  id: DS.attr('string'), 
  image: DS.attr('array'), 
  image_highres: DS.attr('string'), 
  image_lowres: DS.attr('string'), 
  map_background: DS.attr('string'), 
  ne_lat: DS.attr('string'), 
  ne_long: DS.attr('string'), 
  order: DS.attr('string'), 
  sw_lat: DS.attr('string'), 
  sw_long: DS.attr('string'), 
  timestmap: DS.attr('string'), 
  title: DS.attr('string'), 
  track_geojson: DS.attr('string'), 
  type: DS.attr('string'), 
  zoom: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Now what is supposed to be the workflow with ajax and ember-data? Where do I need to put the ajax call and where do I store it in the models?

EDIT:
I managed to push them to the store, but when I try to access it:

```
this.store.pushPayload( normalizedData );;
console.log( "maps: ", normalizedData );
console.log(this.store.findAll('map'));
return normalizedData;
```

I get:

```
http://localhost:4200/maps 404 (Not Found)
```

I suppose I need to rewrite the findAll method in an adapter, but how would this method look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're requesting data from an external endpoint, I'd use [`pushPayload()`](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/#toc_pushing-records) to run the returned data through the `map` model's serializer:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    const mapData = ajax({
      url: '*********************',
      type: 'get' 
    });

    return mapData.then((data) => {
      return this.store.pushPayload(data);
    });
  }
});
```

Once you have returned data from within the model hook on the route, it's automatically available in the corresponding controller via `this.get('model')`.

From your example, it looks like you might want to manipulate the data after it comes back from the server. There are a few common ways of doing this.

1. The route's [`setupController()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController) and [`afterModel()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_afterModel) hooks.
2. In the route's corresponding controller.

Here's an example of using `setupController()`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.set(controller, 'someAttrForTheController', 'anything');
    console.log('maps: ', model);
  }
});
```

And an example within the corresponding controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  latLongCenters: Ember.computed('model', function() {
    const models = this.get('model');
    return model.map(function(map) {
      return [map.get('gmap_lat_center'), map.get('gmap_long_center')];
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but where do I need to put the ajax call? I can't find this anywhere in the guides..

Comment: The `findAll()` method executes the ajax request. You do not need to call `ajax()` directly. Use the methods listed in the guides: `findRecord()`, `findAll()`, `queryRecord()`, `query()`, `createRecord()`, `save()`, `deleteRecord()`, `destroyRecord()`. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/models/

Comment: So like this var posts = this.store.findAll('post');. not exactly clear on where  I need to put the findAll method, there is no mentioning of that in the guides.

Comment: Yup what you posted looks good. That call goes inside of the model hook in your route file. See my example above.

Comment: Yeah i know, but where do i define the findAll method? I suppose i need to put the ajax call ib the findall method?

Comment: Oh, no you don't need to define the query methods. They're part of ember data.

Comment: So I still don't know where to put my api call. :p i need to put it somewhere because ember-data needs to get his data from somewhere

Comment: `findAll` does the call to the API

Comment: Where do I put "url: '*********************',"

Comment: Or put in another way, how do I put data from my API into the ember-data store?

Comment: Ok everything worked, I have pushed my normalizedData to the store. However when I try to access the store (just for testing) I get "http://localhost:4200/maps 404 (Not Found)" what's the point of storing some data in the store when I cant query for it?

Comment: How are you accessing the store?